# Clone repository and "checkout" to "tags/<my_tag>

Tags: python-3.x, git, gitpython

I clone a repository using `Repo.clone_from()`. Afterwards, I simply want to switch to a specified tag within the repository, similar to `git checkout tags/<my_tag>`.

I found the following solution, but it resets HEAD of my masterbranch, which is not what I want:

```
        logging.info("Cloning repo... " + name)
        repo = Repo.clone_from(url, path)
        repo.head.reference = repo.tags[tag].commit
```

Is it possible to perform something like a `git checkout tags/<my_tag>` where I just switch to the current tag, but am able to switch also back to the current / latest commit on the repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer within the [GitPython project QA](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/1026):

```
repo.git.checkout(tag)
```